# Open Edx. Create XBlock. Create the SQLite Database

Tags: edx, openedx

I am following this tutorial to create own XBlock (http://edx.readthedocs.org/projects/xblock-tutorial/en/latest/getting_started/create_first_xblock.html)
When I create the SQLite database:

```
(venv) $ sudo python xblock-sdk/manage.py syncdb
```

I get this error:

```
Error: No module named djpyfs
```

I tried without sudo, But it has errors too:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "xblock-sdk/manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

How to fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: make sure you have followed these steps http://edx.readthedocs.org/projects/xblock-tutorial/en/latest/getting_started/setup_sdk.html,   install requirements

Comment: since you working inside an environment , why are you using `sudo python` ?
just use `python xblock-sdk/manage.py syncdb`

Comment: I know I dont have to use sudo inside an virtual environment, but It helps to install without any errors (in some commands, not in all).

Comment: so `python xblock-sdk/manage.py syncdb` gives you error ?

Comment: Yes, this: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "xblock-sdk/manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Comment: have you installed requirements in your environment ?

Comment: Tutorial says to install requirements do this: (venv) $ pip install -r requirements.txt. But there is no this file in xblock-sdk directory. I have found it in /xblock-sdk/doc and to install requirements  I used this command: (venv) $ pip install -r doc/requirements.txt

Comment: looks like xblock-sdk structure has been changed and the docs are still at the old version.install the requirements using the file requirements/base.txt file.

Comment: check the directory structure and docs here https://github.com/edx/xblock-sdk

Comment: I re-installed XBlock. now it is all OK. Thank you. Frank, how to update my XBlock instance? I wrote in HTML simple text, after I changed but it didnt update.  I did everything. But There is no any result. I treid re install it in virtualenv ((venv) $ sudo pip install -e myxblock). I tried re-install in edx-plathorm (sudo -u edxapp /edx/bin/pip.edxapp install ~/xblock_development/myxblock)

Comment: unistall your old version of custom xblock,  and reinstall it.

Comment: from virtualenv or another ?

Comment: if you want to test your custom xblock in edx, uninstall it from there  and reinstall it.

Comment: We did it! thank you. I am a beginner in EDX and Python. So I ask a lot of questions.

Comment: i dont mind. glad you made it.

Comment: I had to create a var folder in the developmen_directory then change the workbench.log ownership from root to the current user

Comment: had a similar issue, Later I noticed I was not in the "venv". After changing to "venv" things were ok.

Answer (score 0):

make install on sdk directory will solve this.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install django-pyfs==2.0` works for me